# Converting to UTF8 in Laravel project not working

Tags: php, laravel, utf-8, mb-convert-encoding

I am running this line of code.

```
$string = convert_case('MONTAÑA 221');

public function convert_case($string)
{
    $string = mb_convert_case($string, MB_CASE_TITLE, "UTF-8");

    return $string;
}
```

When I run it in laravel I get empty string but when I run it in the browser using just a simple test.php file over wamp, I get the correct string.

Comment: I made a mistake and corrected it in the question

Answer (score 1):

I have seen issues like this before, and maybe yours is different, but setting the encoding of the HTML page may be useful to you.

In the header:

```
<meta charset="utf-8" />
```

Comment: +1 as I've seen other's struggling with this kind of issue too and they've used this to solve a problem.

Comment: oh did I give a solution to the wrong problem? lol.  I'm not a php guy.

Comment: lol something similar to this has been used before but I try not to be overly critical as people who have low reputations could very well be trying to improve their standing on stack overflow.

Answer (score 1):

To address your question based on the code you've posted:

```
                             $string = 'MONTAÑA 221';
                                |
                                v
public function convert_case($string)
{   
    $string = html_entity_decode($input,ENT_COMPAT,"UTF-8");

    $oldLocale = setlocale(LC_CTYPE, '0');  

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, 'en_US.UTF-8');
    $string = iconv("UTF-8","ASCII//TRANSLIT",$string);

    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, $oldLocale);

    return strtolower(preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z0-9]+/','',$string));
}
```

**Output:**

montana221

Code in the space where ever you feel they're needed. This code is specific to running on the backend.
Using HTML's:

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

Could be the reason why it comes out correctly on the front-end.